# mysql query to join, compare two tables and return all records in first table

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

Am trying to compare data from two different tables, by returning all the data from the first table then select available data in second table if has any.

My main aim is to check if student has been enrolled to a course, if yes i will show something to indicate. Below is my table structure and attempt i made.

*courses*

```
course_name             |   course_code
------------------------|---------------------------------
VUE                     | VUE101
OBJECTIVE C             | OBJ101
Java                    | JAVA1
PHP                     | PHP101
HTML                    | HTML5
PYTHON                  | PYT101
SWIFT                   | SWT101
SQL                     | SQL101
HACKZA                  |HK101
```

*student_courses*

```
course_codes        |   student_id
--------------------|---------------------------
VUE                 |   peter123
SWIFT               |   peter123
SQL                 |   peter123
```

/*Attempted SQL Query*/

```
//Query One
SELECT * FROM  courses cs
LEFT OUTER JOIN student_courses scs
ON cs.course_code = scs.course_codes
WHERE scs.student_id = 'peter123'

//Query Two
SELECT * FROM  courses cs
LEFT OUTER JOIN student_courses scs
ON cs.course_code = scs.course_codes
WHERE scs.student_id = 'john123'

/*//PHP Example
foreach($result as $row){
    if($row->course_code == $row->course_codes){
        echo $row->course_code . ' ENROLLED'
    }else{
        echo $row->course_code;
    }
}*/
```

/*Expected Result Query One*/

```
VUE                     ENROLLED
OBJECTIVE C 
Java                        
PHP                     
HTML                    
PYTHON              
SWIFT                   ENROLLED
SQL                     ENROLLED
HACKZA
```

/*Expected Result Query Two*/

```
VUE                     
OBJECTIVE C 
Java                        
PHP                     
HTML                    
PYTHON              
SWIFT                   
SQL                     
HACKZA
```

Comment: Change WHERE to AND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the condition from the WHERE to the ON clause:

```
SELECT 
  cs.course_name,
  case when scs.student_id is not null then 'ENROLLED' end AS ischeck 
FROM  courses cs
LEFT OUTER JOIN student_courses scs
ON cs.course_name = scs.course_codes AND scs.student_id = 'peter123'
```

I joined `cs.course_name` instead of `cs.course_code` to make this work, but I think that in the sample data you posted the 2 columns are by mistake assigned to that data. If this is the case then change to `ON cs.course_code = scs.course_codes`
 
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dUpAhMsznYSek94wTxsWkN/1).
Results:

```
| course_name | ischeck  |
| ----------- | -------- |
| VUE         | ENROLLED |
| SWIFT       | ENROLLED |
| SQL         | ENROLLED |
| OBJECTIVE C |          |
| Java        |          |
| PHP         |          |
| HTML        |          |
| PYTHON      |          |
| HACKZA      |          |
```

Comment: I have tried your answer and it works but am having problem grabbing it from my code is it possible to assign `ischeck AS 'enrolled'` so i can check `if($row->ischeck == 'enrolled')` ?

Comment: When i print out the returned object i got something like this `(object) array(
   'courses_name' => 'English Language',
   'courses_code' => 'ENG101',
   'case when scs.student_id is not null then \'ENROLLED\' end' => 'ENROLLED',
)` I don't really understand how to access this from my php

Comment: I added the alias `ischeck` in th equery.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with just one query.

```
SELECT course_code,  
CASE WHEN course_codes != '' THEN 'ENROLLED' ELSE '' END AS STS
FROM courses
LEFT JOIN student_courses ON (student_courses.course_codes = courses.course_code);
```

Comment: Please how do i use where clause to check for individual student? When i add `WHERE student_courses.student_id = 'peter123'` it only return 3 items

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Select course_name, 
CASE WhEN course_name in (
 Select course_codes From student_courses where student_id = 'peter123') Then 'Enrolled' 
 ElSE ''
 End 
 From courses;
```

To Receive

```
VUE            Enrolled
OBJECTIVE C     
Java    
PHP     
HTML    
PYTHON  
SWIFT          Enrolled
SQL            Enrolled
HACKZA
```

Your second querie i don't understand

Comment: I tried your example and it worked, but how do i get the value of `Enrolled` within my php code?

Comment: That depens what you are using mysqli or pdo. look here this is simpole to adept https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575432/having-trouble-executing-a-select-query-in-a-prepared-statement